# Como usar una variable para estilizar con cssText desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, style

quiero usar una variable para style.cssText de esta manera:

```
let $scrollBtn = document.getElementById("scrollBtn");    
let scrollBtnPos = innerHeight-100;
$scrollBtn.style.cssText = 'right: 3px; top: scrollBtnPos + "px" ';
```

y no encuentro la manera de colocar scrollBtnPos como una variable dentro de la cadena a pasarle a cssText

Comment: Deberías dar más información, muestra que elementos son los que quieres tratar, y así, la parte html y js. El contexto no está muy claro.

Comment: @WilsonPT, $scrollBtn es un div que contiene un i con un icono mdi, creo eso es irrelevante. Solo quiero saber la forma de introducir la variable scrollBtnPos para que no sea tomada como un string. Puedo hacerlo con style.right en una sentencia y con style.top = innerHeight-100 + "px" en otra, solo queria pasar todo en la misma sentencia con cssText.

Comment: Dentro de una cadena no se va a interpretar la variable debes concatenar correctamente: `$scrollBtn.style.cssText = 'right: 3px; top: ' + scrollBtnPos + 'px';`

Comment: @Triby, tu siempre me sacas las papas del fuego, muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Listo Hernán, parece que ya te respondieron.